# What is the maximum value for an int32?

Tags: integer

I can never remember the number. I need a memory rule.

Comment: unsigned: 2³²-1 = 4·1024³-1; signed: -2³¹ .. +2³¹-1, because the sign-bit is the highest bit. Just learn 2⁰=1 to 2¹⁰=1024 and combine.
1024=1k, 1024²=1M, 1024³=1G

Comment: I generally remember that every 3 bits is about a decimal digit. This gets me to the right order of magnitude: 32 bits is 10 digits.

Comment: @JoachimSauer it can certainly help debugging if you learn to at least recognize these kinds of numbers.

Comment: "if a disk becomes full, deleting all mbytes will archive" (2 letters, 1 letter, 4 letters, 7 letters, 4 letters, 8 letters, 3 letters, 6 letters, 4 letters, 7 letters)

Comment: A case, when the int32 is not enough: http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-30288542

Comment: Why on earth do you want to remember the exact number? What @JoachimSauer said is the way you do away with the number.

Comment: @UltraCommit why do you think your way is any more *useful* than plain 2,147,483,647?

Comment: Again, "7 and seven 'f's" is an easy to remember mnemonic! (0x7fffffff) :)

Comment: @Flinkman, file `limits.h` contains all that useful constants and much more.
It would be more appropriate to ask about "where to find all that reference platform-specific values?".

Comment: best way to remember it is not to try but just bookmark some internet page where the number is written on (i. e. this one)

Comment: start with 2...7 days in a week, 2*7=14 that is 2147 now next two are 47+1=48, 214748, next is number of days in year - 1, 365-1=364 and end again with 7. You will now never be able to forget I guess :)

2 14 7 48 364 7 = 2 1 47 48 364 7 = 2147483647

Comment: Slightly less than the view count of Gangnam Style on Youtube

Comment: this kind of question would be shamelessly trashed on today's SO. Especially anywhere near certain regions that shall not be named.

Comment: You can do `(1 << 31) -1` or `(1 << -1) -1` for signed 32-bit or `~0` for unsigned 32-bit.

Comment: Just remember that it's the eighth Mersenne prime.  That should help you remember the number.

Comment: If you are 1337 h4x0r you will remember it with Piata: "Piata ate eg at" ... n00n? Let's say she ate that egg at noon.

Comment: "If I have integer then possible max number isnt fifteen." Instead it's the concatenated lengths of those words. Cool stuff.

Comment: [This post is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387214/6296561)

Answer (score 5058, accepted):

It's 2,147,483,647. Easiest way to memorize it is via a tattoo.

Comment: My mnemonic: 2^10 is very near to 1000, so 2^(3*10) is 1000^3 or about 1 billion. One of the 32 bits is used for sign, so the max value is really only 2^31, which is about twice the amount you get for 2^(3*10): 2 billion.

Comment: @16807 there's used zero bits for sign (on most architectures at least) if there was a bit used for sign there'd be to zeros and the absolut value of the min and max number would be the same but it's not. there's one more negative number than there's positive numbers because the representation is most widely used is two's complement

Comment: @RuneFS fair enough. What I mean to say is there's 32 bits but the extremes must be near 2^31. In any case, the mnemonic is only supposed to be accurate to the nearest billion.

Comment: 2147483647 without commas.

Comment: I did `2^32` and answer came out to be `4294967296`. I think the number you wrote is for signed max value(+ve)....I added  `2,147,483,647 + 2,147,483,647` and the answer came out to be `4294967294`...Its 2 less than what I got with 2^32 any reasoning? @BenHoffstein

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan Imagine it as a zero-based array and take the formula `2^index = value`. `2^0 = 1`, `2^1 = 2`, `2^2 = 4` ... `2^32 = 4294967296` wait ... you only have 32 bits, that is index 0-31. To get max value you actually have to calculate the sum of `2^n` with n from 0 to 31 or simpler `2^32 - 1` and you'll get '4294967295' as max for unsigned int, one less than anticipated. Now do the same with `2^31 - 1` for signed int and you'll get `2,147,483,647`. Do that two times (one for negative and one for positive int) and there you'll get your discrepancy of 2 from `2*(2^31 - 1)` to `2^32` ;)

Comment: Simply use: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in Java.

Comment: 2,147,483,647 = 0x7FFFFFFF, if you wanna remember it, just use hex.

Comment: simple formula (2 << 31) - 1

Comment: @roottraveller At that point, you might as well just remember it in binary; 01111111111111111111111111111111

Comment: @roottraveller 01111111111111111111111111111111 is octal in most languages, 0b01111111111111111111111111111111 would be the correct Java version

Comment: Tue 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 AM UTC is sure going to be fun

Comment: Google =-2^31 for lower boundary and =2^31-1 for upper boundary.

Answer (score 492):

The most correct answer I can think of is `Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: Before this existed, I used to #define INT32_MIN and INT32_MAX in all my projects.

Comment: When you are programming: yes in 99% of cases. But you may want to know that it's something like ~ 2 billion to planning programming approaches or when working with data, although it's a very large number. :)

Comment: @sehe Isn't latin1/Windows 1252 obsolete by now?  If it can't fit in the 7 bytes of ASCII, I don't think it deserves a place in main-memory.  I mean... *all* UNICODE code-pages is kinda useful, but over a meg of skin-space seems a waste.  (Not to mention it still doesn't include descriptive glyphs for "pageup/pagedown" or "pagehome/pageend")

Comment: try that in python2. Actually don't; I will tell you that the built in `int` object does not have this. :(

Comment: This property might be a good advice additionally to mentioning the correct number. However, I don't like this answer as it only mentions an unportable way of dertermining the value and it doesn't mention for which programming languages this is works, either...

Comment: No offense, but can you print the value of `Int32.MaxValue` inside your head? ;-) The question asks for, though absurd, a way to remember the figure

Comment: What language is this? I tried it in my Terminal (ShellScript), Python 3.6.4, and Python 2.7. It doesn't work in any of these!

Comment: @Cubetastic It is .Net Framework (any language really, but I normally code in C#).

Comment: That's not the maximum value. That's the name of a constant.

Answer (score 439):

If you think the value is too hard to remember in base 10, try base 2:
1111111111111111111111111111111

Comment: Wait a minute... That number is negative!

Comment: @Nick Whaley: No, 1111111111111111111111111111111 is positive. 11111111111111111111111111111111 would be negative :-)

Comment: Base 16 it's even easier 7FFFFFFF

Comment: @Curd `11111111111111111111111111111111` as a base-2 number would still be positive *(an example negative in base-2 would be `-1`)*.  That sequence of bits is only negative if representing a 32-bit 2's complement number :)

Comment: Easiest to remember will be base 2,147,483,647. Then all you have to remember is 1.

Comment: @tim_barber_7BB actually, it's 10.

Comment: @tim_barber_7BB then you would have to remember the base "2,147,483,647" , so we are back were we started, this might lead to stack over flow exception.

Comment: The dotted decimal of that is 127.255.255.255. Looks like mix of subnet mask and ip address.

Comment: Base 16 is kind funny 7FFFFFFF is 7 followed by 7 F

Comment: I like the way one can see at a glance that this is correct, especially if you have superpowers

Comment: @big_tommy_7bb, actually it is 10, not 1.

Answer (score 315):

if you can remember the entire Pi number, then the number you are looking for is at the position 1,867,996,680 till 1,867,996,689 of the decimal digits of Pi

> The numeric string 2147483647 appears at the 1,867,996,680 decimal digit of Pi. 3.14......86181221809936452346**2147483647**10527835665425671614...

source: http://www.subidiom.com/pi/

Comment: you know, when i started reading your answer i was expecting something practical, like the 20th digit.

Comment: This seems pretty cool. Do you have another memory rule to remember 1,867,996,680? I find it difficult to remember at which index to start looking....

Comment: "*if you can remember the entire Pi number...*" - no, you can't, it is [*irrational*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) {as are possibly one or two posts in this Q&As} 8-D

Comment: Wow, this is actually pretty intense.

Comment: @Alderath I typically remember it as the 10 decimals in sqrt(2) starting at digit number 380,630,713....

Comment: @SlySven Have to refer you Sнаđошƒаӽ's answer, where he recommends tattoos to aid memory. I love it. I don't think I'd mind seeing a tattoo with the value of pi on it :-)

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins maybe, but a numeric form would always be incomplete, though I suspect a geometric one would be relatively straightforward.  Incidentally, according to [50 Interesting Facts About . . . Pi](http://facts.randomhistory.com/2009/07/03_pi.html) Fact 46: _Thirty-nine decimal places of pi suffice for computing the circumference of a circle girding the known universe with an error no greater than the radius of a hydrogen atom._ (apparently from: Pickover, Clifford A. ___Keys to Infinity___. Denver, CO: John Wiley & Sons, Inc.) So we don't need that many digits of π anyhow!

Comment: Very cool stuff!! You can even search for it using an int type number as index since 1,867,996,680 < 2,147,483,647 !

Comment: @Alderath: The numeric string 1867996680 appears at the 380,630,713rd decimal digit of the Square Root of 2.

Comment: And 380630713 appears at the 779,302,404th decimal digit of Pi and at the 862,984,621st decimal digit of E. Take your pick!

Comment: @Justsalt: That sounds like a bug: it has messed up our loop variant, as now the index, which was going down so promisingly (2,147,483,647 > 1,867,996,680) has ballooned back up again: < 779,302,404.

Answer (score 291):

It's 10 digits, so pretend it's a phone number (assuming you're in the US). 214-748-3647. I don't recommend calling it.

Comment: Speaking of remembering it as a phone number, it seems that there may be some phone spammers using it: http://mrnumber.com/1-214-748-3647

Comment: "There is no "748" exchange in Dallas. This number is fake." - from the page linked by shambleh

Comment: @Steven I don't think they're spammers, just people who accidentally stored the phone number as an `INT` instead of `VARCHAR` in MySQL.

Comment: Tried calling it. It rang a few times then went to the error dial tone. =(

Answer (score 172):

Rather than think of it as one big number, try breaking it down and looking for associated ideas eg:

- 2 maximum snooker breaks (a maximum break is 147)
- 4 years (48 months)
- 3 years (36 months)
- 4 years (48 months)

The above applies to the biggest negative number; positive is that minus one.

Maybe the above breakdown will be no more memorable for you (it's hardly exciting is it!), but hopefully you can come up with some ideas that are!

Comment: That is one of the most complicated mneumonic devices I have seen.  Impressive.

Comment: Heh, the likes of Derren Brown actually advocate this kind of approach - breaking a number down into something random but whieh is more memorable than just a load of numbers:

http://www.channel4.com/entertainment/tv/microsites/M/mindcontrol/remember/memory.html

Comment: I have a better mnemonic: all you need to remember are 2 and 31, as it is apparently exactly 2^31 ! Oh, wait...

Comment: Now that I actually have been typing this in, I keep thinking of your mnemonic... It's rather useful!

Comment: @DrJokepu I am not sure about the operator precedence... Does that mean `2^(31!)` or `(2^31)!`?

Comment: Just note that you should not start this memory device from a [free ball situation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_break#Breaks_exceeding_147)...

Comment: The last two digits are 47, not 48.

Comment: @Lucio Note that my answer relates in the first instance to the biggest negative number which ends in 48, not 47

Comment: @LukeBennett according to http://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/news/alex-higgins/alex-higgins-a-155-break-impossible-not-for-higgy-28548775.html
Higgins is said to be one of the few players in snooker history to have scored a break of 155 — rather remarkable as the 'maximum' is generally considered to be 147. But a 155 is possible, although it requires exceptional circumstances.

Answer (score 144):

Largest negative (32bit) value : -2147483648
(1 << 31)

Largest positive (32bit) value : 2147483647
~(1 << 31)

Mnemonic: "drunk AKA horny"

```
drunk ========= Drinking age is 21
AK ============ AK 47
A ============= 4 (A and 4 look the same)
horny ========= internet rule 34 (if it exists, there's 18+ material of it) 

21 47 4(years) 3(years) 4(years)
21 47 48       36       48
```

Comment: The worlds most difficult to recall Mnemonic. If you can memorise 0118 999 88199 9119 752...3 you can memorise this.

Comment: @Rondles I think it's actually 7253 at the end.

Comment: Ah damn it I did know this and sang it in my head before typing it, how the hell did I get those two mixed up. QQ

Comment: @BenM: "Which country?" :D

Comment: Nope. Drinking age is 18 here... Seems like I can't use this mnemonic, my life is ruined.

Comment: @Aaren Cordova They used to say stackoverflow will never be funny, be  nothing more than a Q&A site, I generally point them to this answer. This thing can only be created inside a genius mind, I mean this *is* Art.

Comment: The largest negative 32 bit integer, or 64 bit  for that matter, is -1.

Answer (score 75):

Anyway, take this regex (it determines if the string contains a non-negative Integer in  decimal form that is also not greater than Int32.MaxValue)

`[0-9]{1,9}|[0-1][0-9]{1,8}|20[0-9]{1,8}|21[0-3][0-9]{1,7}|214[0-6][0-9]{1,7}|2147[0-3][0-9]{1,6}|21474[0-7][0-9]{1,5}|214748[0-2][0-9]{1,4}|2147483[0-5][0-9]{1,3}|21474836[0-3][0-9]{1,2}|214748364[0-7]`

Maybe it would help you to remember.

Comment: That sounds a lot easier and fun to me. Actually it really is much easier than `2147483647`. This would be of great help for the OP

Answer (score 61):

That's how I remembered `2147483647`:

- 214 - because 2.14 is approximately pi-1
- 48 = 6*8
- 64 = 8*8

Write these horizontally:

```
214_48_64_
and insert:
   ^  ^  ^
   7  3  7 - which is Boeing's airliner jet (thanks, sgorozco)
```

Now you've got 2147483647.

Hope this helps at least a bit.

Comment: Nice one!  I think the 214 rule should be pi - 1.  Also the mask shows 68 rather than 64.  =)      For aviation buffs like me, the 737 value should be easy to remember associating it with Boeing's medium-sized airliner jet.

Comment: You can go further than that. Drop the decimal and compare pi and 2^31-1. In the same positions you get 141 vs 147, so the last digit just becomes a 7. Then 592 vs 483, all are one digit off of each other. And 643 vs 647, it's that becoming a 7 thing again.

Comment: @PeterCooper Altho the decimals for pi starts with 1415926_5_35 (Note the 5, not a 4)

Comment: My mnemonic is to take 4294967296 (which is easy to remember) and divide by 2

Answer (score 55):

```
2^(x+y) = 2^x * 2^y

2^10 ~ 1,000
2^20 ~ 1,000,000
2^30 ~ 1,000,000,000
2^40 ~ 1,000,000,000,000
(etc.)

2^1 = 2
2^2 = 4
2^3 = 8
2^4 = 16
2^5 = 32
2^6 = 64
2^7 = 128
2^8 = 256
2^9 = 512
```

So, 2^31 (signed int max) is 2^30 (about 1 billion) times 2^1 (2), or about 2 billion. And 2^32 is 2^30 * 2^2 or about 4 billion. This method of approximation is accurate enough even out to around 2^64 (where the error grows to about 15%).

If you need an exact answer then you should pull up a calculator.

Handy word-aligned capacity approximations:

- 2^16 ~= 64 thousand // uint16
- 2^32 ~= 4 billion // uint32, IPv4, unixtime
- 2^64 ~= 16 quintillion (aka 16 billion billions or 16 million trillions) // uint64, "bigint"
- 2^128 ~= 256 quintillion quintillion (aka 256 trillion trillion trillions) // IPv6, GUID

Comment: That's what the hard-drive makers said.

Answer (score 46):

Just take any decent calculator and type in "7FFFFFFF" in hex mode, then switch to decimal.

2147483647.

Comment: Any decent calculator can do 2^31 as well.

Comment: I don't know 2^31 seems like the long way to do it :/

Comment: Or just remember it in hex

Comment: Just... **write** it in hex. Or `Int32.MaxValue`/`numeric_limits<int32_t>::max()`

Comment: @Christoffer It is actually 2^31 - 1 :)

Comment: any calculator that supports hexadecimal would support bitwise operations as well, so simply type 0 and press `NOT` button

Answer (score 36):

It's about `2.1 * 10^9`. No need to know the exact `2^{31} - 1 = 2,147,483,647`.

## C

You can find it in C like that:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

main() {
    printf("max int:\t\t%i\n", INT_MAX);
    printf("max unsigned int:\t%u\n", UINT_MAX);
}
```

gives (well, without the `,`)

```
max int:          2,147,483,647
max unsigned int: 4,294,967,295
```

## C++ 11

```cpp11
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << "\n";
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() << "\n";
```

## Java

You can get this with Java, too:

```java
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

But keep in mind that Java integers are always signed.

## Python 2

Python has arbitrary precision integers. But in Python 2, they are mapped to C integers. So you can do this:

```py
import sys
sys.maxint
>>> 2147483647
sys.maxint + 1
>>> 2147483648L
```

So Python switches to `long` when the integer gets bigger than `2^31 -1`

Comment: The Python answer is outdated see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795758/what-is-sys-maxint-in-python-3

Comment: @NOhs I appreciate the link, but my Python answer is about "Python 2" (I add the 2 to the section title to make it more clear). So my answer is not outdated. (But Python 2, admittedly, is)

Answer (score 35):

Here's a mnemonic for remembering 2**31, subtract one to get the maximum integer value.

a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,g=7,h=8,i=9

```
Boys And Dogs Go Duck Hunting, Come Friday Ducks Hide
2    1   4    7  4    8        3    6      4     8
```

I've used the powers of two up to 18 often enough to remember them, but even I haven't bothered memorizing 2**31. It's too easy to calculate as needed or use a constant, or estimate as 2G.

Comment: What do you do for 2^10, 2^11, 2^12, or 2^17 (all of which have zeroes)?

Comment: @supercat I'd either rebase a=0, or use o=0.

Answer (score 31):

32 bits, one for the sign, 31 bits of information:

```
2^31 - 1 = 2147483647
```

Why -1?
Because the first is zero, so the greatest is the **count minus one**.

**EDIT for [cantfindaname88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695655/cantfindaname88)**

The count is 2^31 but the greatest can't be 2147483648 (2^31) because we count from 0, not 1.

```
Rank   1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 2147483648
Number 0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 2147483647
```

Another explanation with only 3 bits : 1 for the sign, 2 for the information

```
2^2 - 1 = 3
```

Below all the possible values with 3 bits: (2^3 = 8 values)

```
1: 100 ==> -4
2: 101 ==> -3
3: 110 ==> -2
4: 111 ==> -1
5: 000 ==>  0
6: 001 ==>  1
7: 010 ==>  2
8: 011 ==>  3
```

Comment: @cantfindaname88: 2^31 = total combinations, so it ranges from 0 to (2^31 -1). Yes the first is 0.

Answer (score 30):

Well, it has 32 bits and hence can store 2^32 different values. Half of those are negative.

The solution is 2,147,483,647

And the lowest is −2,147,483,648.

(Notice that there is one more negative value.)

Comment: It has 32 bits and hence can store 2^32 values. No less.

Answer (score 28):

**Well, aside from jokes, if you're really looking for a useful memory rule, there is one that I always use for remembering big numbers.**

You need to break down your number into parts from 3-4 digits and remember them visually using projection on your cell phone keyboard. It's easier to show on a picture:

[image]

As you can see, from now on **you just have to remember 3 shapes, 2 of them looks like a Tetris L and one looks like a tick**. Which is definitely much easier than memorizing a 10-digit number.

When you need to recall the number just recall the shapes, imagine/look on a phone keyboard and project the shapes on it. Perhaps initially you'll have to look at the keyboard but after just a bit of practice, you'll remember that numbers are going from top-left to bottom-right so you will be able to simply imagine it in your head.

Just make sure you remember the direction of shapes and the number of digits in each shape (for instance, in 2147483647 example we have a 4-digit Tetris L and a 3-digit L).

You can use this technique to easily remember any important numbers (for instance, I remembered my 16-digit credit card number etc.).

Comment: Neat idea! Shape 1 gives you 2147, Shape 2 gives you 483, and Shape 3 is supposed to give 647, but as drawn, it could be interpreted as 6**5**47. How do I know when to include all the crossed numbers (as in Shape 1) vs. when to skip some (as in Shape 3)? You also have to memorize that the shapes encode 4, 3, and 3 digits, respectively. Or you could draw Shape 3 with an arc from 6 to 4 instead of a straight line.

Comment: @Squinch Well, particularly for remembering int.Max it shouldn't be a problem as you might know that it's about 2 billion so it has 10 numbers in it (and that means if the first shape has 4 numbers then the second and the third shapes have 3 accordingly). However, that's a nice point if you want to use this approach for any number. Also, there are numbers that are difficult to remember using this way (i.e. 1112 or something). On the other hand, it shouldn't be difficult to remember such number anyway. So I'd say it's up to you, let me know if you come up with something interesting for this. :)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about using this method to recall an arbitrary sequence of digits, but for this particular int.Max value, your method works fairly well. As you said, repeated digits are a problem. In fact, any repeated sequence (such as 2323) is a problem. Any sequence that crosses itself (such as 2058) is difficult to draw. Any memorization technique requires you to remember several pieces of information. It's personal preference what types of info best stick in your head.

Comment: This is how I remember pin codes and similar, but then all of a sudden you need to type it in on your computer and realize that the numpad is vertically flipped. So that's a bit of a challenge.

Comment: Somebody in [Dallas, Texas](https://www.worldatlas.com/na/us/tx/area-code-214.html), has received many strange phone calls and has no idea that you @IvanYurchenko are to blame.

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way to do this for integers is to use hexadecimal, provided that there isn't something like Int.maxInt(). The reason is this:

Max unsigned values

```
8-bit 0xFF
16-bit 0xFFFF
32-bit 0xFFFFFFFF
64-bit 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
128-bit 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Signed values, using 7F as the max signed value

```
8-bit 0x7F
16-bit 0x7FFF
32-bit 0x7FFFFFFF
64-bit 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Signed values, using 80 as the max signed value

```
8-bit 0x80
16-bit 0x8000
32-bit 0x80000000
64-bit 0x8000000000000000
```

How does this work? This is very similar to the binary tactic, and each hex digit is exactly 4 bits. Also, a lot of compilers support hex a lot better than they support binary.

```
F hex to binary: 1111
8 hex to binary: 1000
7 hex to binary: 0111
0 hex to binary: 0000
```

So 7F is equal to 01111111 / 7FFF is equal to 0111111111111111. Also, if you are using this for "insanely-high constant", 7F... is safe hex, but it's easy enough to try out 7F and 80 and just print them to your screen to see which one it is.

0x7FFF + 0x0001 = 0x8000, so your loss is only one number, so using 0x7F... usually isn't a bad tradeoff for more reliable code, especially once you start using 32-bits or more

Answer (score 21):

First write out 47 twice, (you like [Agent 47](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman:_Agent_47), right?), keeping spaces as shown (each dash is a slot for a single digit. First 2 slots, then 4)

```
--47----47
```

Think you have `12` in hand (because 12 = a dozen). Multiply it by `4`, first digit of Agent 47's number, i.e. `47`, and place the result to the right of first pair you already have

```
12 * 4 = 48
--4748--47 <-- after placing 48 to the right of first 47
```

Then multiply `12` by `3` (in order to make second digit of Agent 47's number, which is `7`, you need `7 - 4 = 3`) and put the result to the right of the first 2 pairs, the last pair-slot

```
12 * 3 = 36
--47483647 <-- after placing 36 to the right of first two pairs
```

Finally drag digits one by one from your hand starting from right-most digit (2 in this case) and place them in the first empty slot you get

```
2-47483647 <-- after placing 2
2147483647 <-- after placing 1
```

There you have it! For negative limit, you can think of that as 1 more in *absolute value* than the positive limit.

Practise a few times, and you will get the hang of it!

Answer (score 20):

2GB

(is there a minimum length for answers?)

Comment: @JoukevanderMaas - Actually, it should be 4B.

Comment: Which is why the limit of RAM you can have on a 32bit computer is 4GB

Comment: the value of 4GB is correct with unsigned integers. if you have a signed int, you obviously need to divide by 2 to get the max value possible

Comment: @SerjSagan It's 3GB in Windows 32-bit AFAIK. Not sure why!

Comment: In 32-bit there is 2GB of the memory-space reserve for user process, and 2GB for kernel. It can be configured so kernel have only 1 GB reserved

Comment: @atoMerz: You probably have a 1GB video card which only leaves 3GB for regular RAM.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming .NET -

```
Console.WriteLine(Int32.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 15):

If you happen to know your [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) off by heart and not `MaxInt` :
`!GH6G = 21 47 48 36 47`

Comment: When I wrote this answer I didn't know GH6G had so many Google hits, and now I've used this myself :-)

Answer (score 15):

**The best rule to memorize it is:**
**21** (magic number!)
**47** (just remember it)
**48** (sequential!)
**36** (21 + 15, both magics!)
**47** again

Also it is easier to remember 5 pairs than 10 digits.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to remember is to look at  `std::numeric_limits< int >::max()`

For example ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s086ab1z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)),

```
// numeric_limits_max.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout << "The maximum value for type float is:  "
        << numeric_limits<float>::max( )
        << endl;
   cout << "The maximum value for type double is:  "
        << numeric_limits<double>::max( )
        << endl;
   cout << "The maximum value for type int is:  "
        << numeric_limits<int>::max( )
        << endl;
   cout << "The maximum value for type short int is:  "
        << numeric_limits<short int>::max( )
        << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Interestingly, Int32.MaxValue has more characters than 2,147,483,647.

But then again, we do have code completion,

So I guess all we really have to memorize is `Int3<period>M<enter>`, which is only 6 characters to type in visual studio.

**UPDATE**
For some reason I was downvoted. The only reason I can think of is that they didn't understand my first statement.

"Int32.MaxValue" takes at most 14 characters to type.
2,147,486,647 takes either 10 or 13 characters to type depending on if you put the commas in or not.

Comment: But what counts is not how many characters you have to type, but how to memoize it. I'm sure `Iwannagohome` is easier to memoize than `298347829`. No reason for a -1, however.

Comment: It could be less than that, just make your own max value snippet, "imv" <tab> <tab> perhaps?

Comment: Characters `!=` Keystrokes. For this poor .Net user, it's `in`+`.`+`ma`+Return.

Answer (score 10):

Just remember that 2^(10*x) is approximately 10^(3*x) - you're probably already used to this with kilobytes/kibibytes etc.  That is:

```
2^10 = 1024                ~= one thousand
2^20 = 1024^2 = 1048576    ~= one million
2^30 = 1024^3 = 1073741824 ~= one billion
```

Since an int uses 31 bits (+ ~1 bit for the sign), just double 2^30 to get approximately 2 billion.  For an unsigned int using 32 bits, double again for 4 billion.  The error factor gets higher the larger you go of course, but you don't need the exact value memorised (If you need it, you should be using a pre-defined constant for it anyway).  The approximate value is good enough for noticing when something might be a dangerously close to overflowing.

Comment: Offtopic:  2^4 = 4^2, therefore exponentiation is commutative!

Comment: @Pier-OlivierThibault nope, I use it all the time! now I need to find out why all my math is coming out wrong. probably something to do with multiplication errors. anyway, bye!

Answer (score 9):

this is how i do it to remember 2,147,483,647

### To a far savannah quarter optimus trio hexed forty septenary

```
2 - To
1 - A
4 - Far
7 - Savannah
4 - Quarter
8 - Optimus
3 - Trio
6 - Hexed
4 - Forty
7 - Septenary
```

Answer (score 7):

What do you mean? It should be easy enough to remember that it is 2^32.
If you want a rule to memorize the value of that number, a handy rule of thumb is for converting between binary and decimal in general:

2^10 ~ 1000

which means 2^20 ~ 1,000,000

and 2^30 ~ 1,000,000,000

Double that (2^31) is rounghly 2 billion, and doubling that again (2^32) is 4 billion.

It's an easy way to get a rough estimate of any binary number. 10 zeroes in binary becomes 3 zeroes in decimal.

Comment: but it's not 2^32 - it's (2^31)-1

Answer (score 6):

**In Objective-C (iOS & OSX), just remember these macros:**

```c
#define INT8_MAX         127
#define INT16_MAX        32767
#define INT32_MAX        2147483647
#define INT64_MAX        9223372036854775807LL

#define UINT8_MAX         255
#define UINT16_MAX        65535
#define UINT32_MAX        4294967295U
#define UINT64_MAX        18446744073709551615ULL
```

Answer (score 5):

Int32 means you have 32 bits available to store your number. The highest bit is the sign-bit, this indicates if the number is positive or negative. So you have 2^31 bits for positive and negative numbers.

With zero being a positive number you get the logical range of (mentioned before)

+2147483647 to -2147483648

If you think that is to small, use Int64:

+9223372036854775807 to -9223372036854775808

And why the hell you want to remember this number? To use in your code? You should always use Int32.MaxValue or Int32.MinValue in your code since these are static values (within the .net core) and thus faster in use than creating a new int with code.

My statement: if know this number by memory.. you're just showing off!

Comment: Most modern computers store numbers in "twos compliment" format. The highest (not lowest) bit is the sign. The neat thing with twos compement is that -ve numbers are handled by the natural overflow rules of the CPU. i.e 0xFF is 8 bit -1, add that to 0x01 (+1) and you get 0x100. Truncate bits above 8 to 0x00 and you have your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Remember this:
21 IQ ITEM 47

It can be de-encoded with any phone pad, or you can just write one down yourself on a paper.

In order to remember "21 IQ ITEM 47", I would go with "Hitman:Codename 47 had 21 missions, which were each IQ ITEM's by themselves".

Or "I clean teeth at 21:47 every day, because I have high IQ and don't like items in my mouth".

Comment: What do you mean with `de-encoded with any phone pad`?

Answer (score 4):

With Groovy on the path:

```
groovy -e " println Integer.MAX_VALUE "
```

(Groovy is extremely useful for quick reference, within a Java context.)

Answer (score 4):

Just remember that it's the eighth Mersenne prime.

If that's too hard, it's also the third of only four known *double* Mersenne primes.

**Edit per comment request:**

The Euclid-Euler theorem states that every even perfect number has the form 2^(n − 1) (2^n − 1), where 2^n − 1 is a prime number. The prime numbers of the form 2^n − 1 are known as Mersenne primes, and require n itself to be prime.

We know that the length of an INT32 is of course 32 bits. Given the generally accepted understanding of 2's complement, a signed INT32 is 32 bits - 1 bit.

To find the magnitude of a binary number with a given number of bits we generally raise 2 to the power n, minus 1, where n is equal to the number of bits.

Thus the magnitude calculation is 2^(32 - 1) - 1 = 2^31 - 1. 31 is prime and as outlined above, prime numbers of this form are Mersenne primes. We can prove it is the eight of such simply by counting them. For further details, please ask Euler, or maybe Bernoulli (to whom he wrote about them).

See: https://books.google.ie/books?id=x7p4tCPPuXoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=9780883853283&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilzbORuJLdAhUOiaYKHcsZD-EQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=9780883853283&f=false

Comment: Any Reference you could link to...? (Directly, without having to google/wikipediaze...)

Answer (score 4):

2147483647

Here's what you need to remember:

- It's **2 billion**.
- The next three triplets are increasing like so: **100s, 400s, 600s**
- The first and the last triplet need **3** added to them so they get rounded up to **50** (eg 147 + 3 = 150 & 647 + 3 = 650)
- The second triplet needs **3** subtracted from it to round it down to **80** (eg 483 - 3 = 480)

Hence 2, 147, 483, 647

Answer (score 4):

I made a couple genius methods in C# that you can take advantage of in your production environment:

```
public static int GetIntMaxValueGenius1()
{
    int n = 0;
    while (++n > 0) { }
    return --n;
}

public static int GetIntMaxValueGenius2()
{
    int n = 0;
    try
    {
        while (true)
            n = checked(n + 1);
    }
    catch { }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of some kind of method that would guess trillions of random integers, and return the highest one.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I remember...
In hex, a digit represents four bits, so 4 * 8 = 32, so the max signed 32 bit int is:

```
0xFFFFFFFF >> 1 # => 2147483647
```

Comment: This would probably work. I wish the guy that downvoted you would give you an explanation.

Comment: @JoePlante The question asker was asking for a way that he, as a human, could memorize the number (as in, its decimal digits). I don't know about you, but parsing hexadecimal and then bit shifting isn't an intuitive operation on my mental hardware. If you're going to take this approach, you might as well just calculate 2^31-1.

Comment: The question I was answering was "What is the maximum value for a int32?"  I do see your point @MarkAmery, but remembering to type this line into an interpreter or into a print statement is actually how I remember the numbers.  It also works as a general pattern for other sizes.  Thank you for the support @JoePlante!

Comment: No problem. After 16 bits, I simply stopped memorizing because you can always look it up. 0xFFFFFFFF >> 1 I feel is correct in a lot of cases because if you need to go to 64 bits, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF >> 1 also works. 0xFFFF >> 1 and 0xFF >> 1 also works. I'm not sure if this works in languages with signed values or not, but still I feel it's viable

Answer (score 2):

To never forget the maximum value of any type:

If it has 32 bits, the largest possible value would be the 32 bits with the number 1:

[image]

The result would be 4294967295 in decimal:

[image]

But, as there is also the representation of negative numbers, divide 4294967295 by 2 and get 2147483647.

Therefore, a 32-bit integer is capable of representing -2147483647 to 2147483647

Comment: You can, you know, just get 2^31 (which is indeed also how it is stored in ram- one bit for positive/negative flag and 31 bits for the number), which will automatically be the half. And subtract one for the number zero (in your case you get 2147483647.5, not 2147483647 as you don't account for that).

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to remember. In hexadecimal one digit is 4 bits. So for unsigned int write `0x` and 8 `f`s (`0xffffffff`) into a Python or Ruby shell to get the value in base 10. If you need the signed value, just remember that the highest bit is used as the sign. So you have to leave that out. You only need to remember that the number where the lower 3 bits are 1 and the 4th bit is 0 equals 7, so write `0x7fffffff` into a Python or Ruby shell. You could also write `0x100000000 - 1` and `0x80000000 - 1`, if that is more easy to you to remember.

Answer (score 1):

You will find in binary the maximum value of an Int32 is 1111111111111111111111111111111
but in ten based you will find it is 2147483647 or 2^31-1 or Int32.MaxValue

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 9's REPL, [jshell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JShell):

```
$ jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9-Debian

jshell> System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
2147483647
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in Python:

```
>>> int('1' * 31, base=2)
2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

In C use `INT32_MAX` after `#include <stdint.h>`.
In C++ use `INT32_MAX` after `#include <cstdint>`.

Or `INT_MAX` for platform-specific size or `UINT32_MAX` or `UINT_MAX` for `unsigned int`.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/.

Or `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

In general you could do a simple operation which reflects the very nature of a Int32, fill all the available bits with 1's - That is something which you can hold easily in your memory. It works basically the same way in most languages, but i'm going with Python for the example:

```
max = 0
bits = [1] * 31 # Generate a "bit array" filled with 1's
for bit in bits:
    max = (max << 1) | bit
# max is now 2147483647
```

For unsigned Int32's, make it 32 instead of 31 1's.

But since there are posted a few more adventurous approaches, i began to think of formulas, just for the fun of it...

**Formula 1** (Numbers are concatenated if no operator is given)

- a = 4
- b = 8
- ba/a
- ab-1
- ab
- ab-a-b
- ab-1

*Python quickcheck*

```
a = 4
b = 8
ab = int('%d%d' % (a, b))
ba = int('%d%d' % (b, a))
'%d%d%d%d%d' % (ba/a, ab-1, ab, ab-a-b, ab-1)
# gives '2147483647'
```

**Formula 2**

- x = 48
- x/2-3
- x-1
- x
- x*3/4
- x-1

*Python quickcheck*

```
x = 48
'%d%d%d%d%d' % (x/2-3, x-1, x, x*3/4, x-1) 
# gives '2147483647'
```

Answer (score 0):

"If a huge integer isn't recalled, you recall this mnemonic."

Now count the letters in each word.

Answer (score -1):

```
max_signed_32_bit_num = 1 << 31 - 1;  // alternatively ~(1 << 31)
```

A compiler should optimize it anyway.

I prefer `1 << 31 - 1` over

`0x7fffffff` because you don't need count `f`s

`unsigned( pow( 2, 31 ) ) - 1` because you don't need `<math.h>`

Comment: You can use underscores to improve the readability of some languages. Java and Swift support this from what I know, perhaps others. `0x7FFF_FFFF`

Answer (score -1):

It's 2<sup>31</sup> − 1 (32 bits, one is used for sign).

If you want an approximate value, use 2<sup>10</sup> = 1024 ≈ 10<sup>3</sup>, so 2<sup>31</sup> ≈ 2*10<sup>9</sup>. If you want to compute an exact value by hand, use exponentiation by squaring to get to 2<sup>32</sup> = 2<sup>(2<sup>5</sup>)</sup> and divide by two. You only need to square five times to get 2<sup>32</sup>:

```
2*2 = 4
4*4 = 16
16*16 = 256
256*256 = 25*25*100 + 2*250*6 + 36 = 62500 + 3000 + 36 = 65536
65536*65536 =65000*65000 + 2*65000*536 + 536*536 =  
4225000000 + 130000*536 + (250000 + 3600 + 36*36) =
4225000000 + 69680000 + 250000 + 3600 + 1296 =
4294967296
```

dividing this by two and subtracting one gives you 2,147,483,647. If you don't need all digits, but only want say, the first three significant digits, the computations on each squaring step are very easy.