# Value was either too large or too small for an Int32

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum value for a int32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32)

```
Mobileno = Convert.ToInt32(txmobileno.Text);
```

error i amm getting while inserting in to database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32

Comment: What is the exact data type in the database table?

Comment: You need to check your DataType in your DB table.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard In database Data type as int

Comment: @vignesh what version of SQL Server? Can you post the line of code causing the actual error?

Comment: How about a TryParser instead of a convert.

Comment: Storing Mobile number in number format makes no sense. You should use string data type for storing such values consider first part of answer by @mattdavey

Answer (score 58):

Why on earth would you use an integer of any type to store a phone number?

You can't meaningfully do any arithmetics on one and you lose all leading zeroes.

Use a string instead.

Comment: Why on earth would you not give an reasonable answer on how to parse numbers with more than 10 digits. instead of asking him to use string ?

Comment: string startTxt = "1234567891011";
long start = Convert.ToInt64(startTxt);   This is the answer people would be expecting instead.

Comment: Why do you think a it makes sense to represent a phone number as an integer? That you sometimes *can* doesn't mean you should. What would your "start" long value mean? What if the phone number is "001122345676"? How do you know the number of leading zeroes (which is probably significant for a phone number)?

Answer (score 17):

An `integer` (Int32) is limited in the values it can store since it "only" uses 32 bits. It can store a value between 2,147,483,647 and -2,147,483,648. ([More information on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx))

The value represented by the `txmobileno.Text`, is too large or too small.

Looking at the name `txmobileno` is probably a mobile phone number. This kind of numbers have too much digits to store in an `int32`. Also a phone number tends to start with a 0 or 00 or + (international). There's no way of storing this kind of information in an integer (or another number type). Just store them in a `string`.

Comment: On the plus side, phone numbers in my state in the United States typically run 503-nnn-nnnn or 541-nnn-nnnn which means _I_ can't be bothered by poorly-written autodialers that assume an integer can hold any phone number. :)

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, storing a phone number as an integer is a mistake.

- You lose the ability to store characters and whitespace, for example country codes - "+44 (0800) 12345".
- There is no logical reason to store it as an integer - would you ever need to do arithmetic on two telephone numbers? Does it make sense to add two phone numbers together?
- Leading zeros will be lost - (0800 12345) will become (80012345).
- Storing it as a string allows you to do regex validation on the user input.

Having said that, the original question does raise some points which should be made:

- Prefer Int32.TryParse instead of Convert.ToInt32 when the source value is a string.
- When dealing with values which may potentially overflow - enclose the code in a checked { ... } block.

Comment: Int32.TryParse is better. Thanks @MattDavey