# Returning Float Instead Of Integer

Tags: php, floating-point, integer

```
/* returns tweetDetails */
function returnTweets()
{
    $return = array();
    $url = $hashtagSearchUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23gencsengeleceksin&include_entities=1&result_type=recent&rpp=50";
    foreach(json_decode(file_get_contents($url))->results as $t)
    {
        $return[] = $t;
    }

    return $return;
}

/* assigns tweet details to a variable */
$ts = returnTweets();

foreach ($ts as $t)
    echo $t->id."<br />";
```

This must output a list of tweet id's . For example :

```
190914827918857531
190914827918845655
165456467265456156
```

Generally it's working but at **some servers** it's returning something like this:

```
1.9090219393785E+17
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Here's my guess:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32

Comment: @j08691 you can't unless you want to write your own JSON parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably on 32-bit servers.

Get the property `id_str` instead of `id` which will always be a string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use id_str instead of id. 32-bit PHP (which is what most people have installed) cannot handle integers larger than 32 bits.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-ids-json-and-snowflake

Comment: Technically, 32-bit PHP cannot handle integers larger than 32 bits. 64-bit PHP can.

Answer (score 1):

size of integers depend on the platform. you should probably use strings instead of numbers to manipulate that data.