# Data type for Credit card Details using asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

Am kind confused, am try to the max  and min length of the datatype int in my credit card details and telephone but i don't how to.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telephone is required")]
    public int Telephone { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Card Type is required")]
    [DisplayName("Card Type")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CardType { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Card Holders Name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Card Holders Name")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string CardHoldersName { get; set; }
    public int CardNumber { get; set; }
    public int CardExpMonth { get; set; }
    public int CardExpYear { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public decimal Total;
```

Comment: Have you looked into the fun that is PCI compliance? Most people should't be storing CC data, at all.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you storing the card number in an integer? Isn't a string more appropriate?

A string can handle any cc number you need. It could also handle (for further processing) cases where the user enters spaces between digits.

Comment: if i store it string how do i make sure that the user enters numbers only and 16 numbers only

Comment: @user1335443 with validation `:)`

Comment: You have a few choices. Perhaps the best is to use a RegEx validator that verifies these things. Also note that not all credit card numbers are 16 digits.

Comment: @  MДΓΓ БДLL more specif please

Comment: @Jonathan Wood can you give me an example please

Comment: This is not an appropriate forum for describing all the details of MVC validators. Google `asp.net mvc regex validator` if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to store the `CardNumber` in a numeric format, use a `long`. [A 32-bit signed `int`'s max value is `2,147,483,647`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32) — remember, [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is [synonymous with `System.Int32`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care) — which is not remotely large enough to hold a 16-digit credit card number. A [`long` (aka `System.Int64`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has max value of `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, so it can hold every 18-digit number.

Note that a `uint` (unsigned 32-bit integer) is still not large enough, since its max value is merely `4,294,967,295`.

Answer (score 0):

use `BigInteger` Structure available in namespace `System.Numerics`

I think this would be useful to you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

working with incredibly large numbers in .NET

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class