# can't understand the nature of time() and date() in php

Tags: php, date, time

```
date("Y",1340896077)//1340896077 are the seconds till 2012 from 1970
```

gives 2012 which is normal

```
And date("Y",1940896077)
```

gives 2031 which is also normal

**But** `date("Y",2240896077)`

is giving 1904 which is absolutely not at all normal .It should rather give 2041.

Now i want some explanation on time() and date() in php.

Comment: you can call also echo PHP_INT_MAX; to check the maximum integer and suddenly all become (sadly) clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the [Y2K38 bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). `2240896077` is too large for a 32bit integer and it overflows.

Comment: what is the max value on 64 bit system

Comment: oh bigint of mysql is 64 bit,then why that is supported in my system

Comment: Possibly your PHP wasn't *compiled* as 64bit PHP. But I also don't think that MySQL's *storage requirements* have much to do with the system it's running on, contrary to PHP.

Answer (score 7):

PHP uses 32bit integers.

32 bit integer is limited to [2,147,483,647](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32)

In your third example the value is overflowed. Think of it like a car KM counter. Its limited to some value (in our case 2,147,483,647) and once you go pass this value its back to 0.

This can cause the [Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) (remember Year 2000 bug? Similar concept).

In "Minutes of PHP Developers Meeting" there was a [proposal to add 64bit integer](http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#add-a-64bit-integer), I'm not sure how far it went and what is their policy regrading time related functions.

Hope this help :)

Comment: @Somebody is in trouble I can't tell you. Afaik this is going to affect a lot of language (Like C/C++ programs, they use time_t which is unsigned integer which on 32bit system is.. 32bit wide). Static typed language will have to be moved (more likely) to 64bit ints, what about PHP I'm not sure, but I saw a proposal for 64bit int in PHP (cant find the proposal).

Comment: PHP already works fine with 64bit ints on 64bit systems today. We just all need to move to 64bit systems within the next ~25 years.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from
>   01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0 this range was limited from
>   01-01-1970 to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g. Windows).

From:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Amazing co-incidence :). We both hit the answer button at the same time and surprisingly the same answer.