# What is wrong with this c# syntax?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = 600851475143;
        int x = 1;
        While (x<n)
        {
        if(n%x==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }    
        x++;
        }    
    }    
}
```

Gives me a { out of place error, but I can't see whats wrong. Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`While` should not be capitalized, and your  value of `n` is too large for an int.

You don't seem to have a problem with braces. If you fix those two errors it should compile.

Edit: The code file you posted is a completely different error than the one you posted in the question. A C# program can only have one entry point, which is what `public static void Main()` does. If you copy and pasted the method signature from the `Program` file it is not going to compile. Change `Main` to any other valid signature and it should compile.

Comment: You're correct but I still get "Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings Test.cs" Line 10 Column 8 - Unexpected symbol `{'

Comment: @idb, then that error is coming from somewhere other than what you've posted in your question. If I copy and paste it exactly as-is and fix those two errors, it compiles.

Comment: if `while` is written correctly (i.e. in lowercase) you should not get this error.

Comment: With `While` capitalized, the compiler likely think it's a method call, and it does not understand the `{` immediately after the method call (no semicolon `;`).

Comment: That website shows a completely different error, caused by you having two `Main` functions in different files. But don't ask me how it's even possible to set multiple entry points in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

`While (x<n)` should be `while (x<n)`

And you are assigining a `long` value to an `int` variable.

The [maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32) an `int` varibale can hold is **2,147,483,647**; So you may change that to long

```
long  n = 600851475143;
```