# Difference between an array and vector related to maximum size?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

When i run this code in my Devcpp compiler->

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++)
    vec.push_back(i);
}
```

It works even on run time.
But when i run->

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int arr[1000000000];
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me link error.

As long as space is required both arr and vec requires the same space.Then why is it that vec code runs even fine on run time but arr code doesnt even compile.

Comment: @dvenkatsagar no, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @dvenkatsagar That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Jinx. You owe me a soda. :)

Comment: @erip from here, it looks like I was a second faster! so, anyway, meet me, we'll have a soda.

Comment: What compiler error?  It compiles for me with clang on osx.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Could not reproduce a *compilation* error: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bf8cd2f4d65578e

Comment: You need more space to declare such an array. [This question has my result with your code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181501/error1error-c2148-total-size-of-array-must-not-exceed-0x7fffffff-bytes-i-get)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is with the allocation. In the first case, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) default [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) uses dynamic allocation, which in principle can allocate as much memory as you want (bounded of course by the OS and the amount of physical memory) whereas in the second case it uses the memory available for static allocation (technically the array has [static storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)), which in your case is smaller than `1000000000 * sizeof int` bytes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169858/global-memory-management-in-c-in-stack-or-heap) for a nice answer regarding the various types of allocations in a C program (which also applies for C++).

Btw, avoid `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`, as it is non-standard. Include only the **standard** headers you need. One more issue: I don't think you get a compile-time error, you probably get a run-time error. In other words, the code compiles just fine, but fails to run.

Comment: @StevenBurnap I am not sure OP is getting a compile error though, it is probably a run time error. Will edit the answer.

Comment: Yeah, what you say makes perfect sense if the OP got a runtime error.

Comment: `arr` is not defined on the stack. It is a global object.

Comment: @RSahu Missed that it was defined outside the function, will edit, thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah, if it's a global, there should be no limit as long as the index is an integral type.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Are you sure about that? Isn't the global data segment quite small? In any case, the standard does not mandate anything regarding where/how the allocations are being done. And what do you mean by *as long as the index is an integral type*? The size of the array has to be an integral type.

Comment: What I mean is, that the C++ standard only says that it has to be indexed by an integral type, and doesn't specify a maximum size.  The global data segment depends entirely on the platform.  As I noted elsewhere, this compiles and runs perfectly well on OSX using clang.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Ohh I see, yes I completely agree.

Comment: "you probably get a run-time error. In other words, the code compiles just fine, but fails to run." `arr` will be statically stored in the executable; this will therefore get (much) bigger but it won't overflow the stack.

Comment: using a thousand separator in 1'000'000'000 would make the number more readable...

Comment: @Al Bundy In C++14 though

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the object

```
int arr[1000000000];
```

is too large to fit in the global data of your program for your environment. I don't get a compile time error but I get a link time error in my environment also (cygwin/g++ 4.9.3).

Reducing the size by one tenth work for me. It may work for you also. I don't know how you can determine the maximum size of objects that can fit in global data.

Space available in stack is the smallest in size.
Space available in global data is larger that that.
Space available in heap is the largest of all.

If your object is too large to fit in stack, try to put into global data.
If your object is too large to fit in global data, use heap.

Comment: `int arr[1000000000];` is an object? really?

Comment: @StahlRat, In the C++ object model, every variable is an object.

Comment: Annex B of the C++ standard names 262144 as a guideline for maximum object size. If I understand correctly, this means that for a non-dynamic `int` array, anything up to `262144 / sizeof(int)` elements should be fine with a quality implementation. But of course, *"these quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance"*.

Comment: @StahlRat: object not in terms of classes, though. They're rather ADTs (Abstract Data Types).