# Warning: mt_rand(): max(-1) is smaller than min(1)

Tags: php, linux, centos

The following script provides the following output.  I am running PHP Version 5.5.12 with Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) on i386 server.  Note I run the same script on my almost identical server which is x86_64, and I don't experience the error.

```
<?php
$id=mt_rand ( 1 , 4294967295);
?>
```

> Warning: mt_rand(): max(-1) is smaller than min(1) in
>   /var/www/html/testing/mt_rand.php on line 2

What causes this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You happen to use a value that is bigger than the integer maximum. As read in [What is the maximum value for a int32?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/94608/1983854), this value is **2,147,483,647**.

From [PHP.net in mt_rand()](http://www.php.net/mt_rand):

> **Description**
>
> int mt_rand ( void )
>
> int mt_rand ( int $min , int $max )
>
> **Return Values**
>
> A random integer value between min (or 0) and max (or mt_getrandmax(),
> inclusive), **or FALSE if max is less than min**.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value
> of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). PHP
> does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined
> using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant
> PHP_INT_MAX since PHP
> 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

Your script fails on 32 bits systems because you are providing a value which is ~4 billion, while the maximum is ~2 billion. A workaround can be to change `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Comment: not even. that. it's SIGNED 32bit, so ~2billion positive max.

Comment: @MarcB sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I've tried it multiple times, so I am sure I did not just "happen" to hit 4294967295.  That being said, I am sure you are right.  I'll look into `PHP_INT_MAX`.

Comment: 32bit int has a 4 billion range, 0->2^32. But PHP's are signed ints, so it's -2billion -> +2 billion. OP's code would have failed for **ANY** int >= 2,147,483,648.

Comment: @MarcB aaah, true, yes, with anything bigger than that number the output is bad. I will rephrase my answer because I see I did not write it properly. Thanks!

Comment: @user1032531 yes! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32 for more info.

Comment: `PHP_INT_MAX` is not in either server's php.ini file.  Echoing `PHP_INT_MAX` on the server that works shows `9223372036854775807`.  The server that doesn't work shows `2147483647`.  How do I change it?

Comment: Ah, I see.  +/- 2^31 for my i386 server and +/i 2^63 for my x86_64 server.  Since I only want a 2^32 unsigned value, I will change my function to `$id=2147483648+mt_rand(-2147483647,2147483647);`

Answer (score 3):

If you want a value between 1 and 4294967295 which is platform independent, use the following:

```
$id=2147483648+mt_rand(-2147483647,2147483647);
```

This answers part of the question, but fedorqui answered the real question that an integer on some platforms is limited to +/-2,147,483,647.