# Mysql Returning 'Duplicate Entry' When No Duplicate Exists

Tags: mysql

Weird issue:

```
ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '21474836476' for key 'twitterid'
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `database`.`wp_table` (`id`, `twitterid`) VALUES ('34', '33456305746')
```

Even though I typed in 33456305746, it thinks I am typing in 21474836476. Now this row does exist already so I tried deleting it and it saves the row with a value of 21474836476. If I remove the unique requirement it saves both rows as 21474836476. Anyone know what in the world is going on here?

Comment: Please post your table structure. Maybe your datatype is too small.

Comment: Looks very close to max int32: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-a-int32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`21474836476` is (close to) the max value of an `integer` which is the data type of your field.

`33456305746` is bigger and the DB truncates the value to the max `integer` which you already inserted at some time before.

Change the data type of the field to `bigint` if you need such high numbers.