# Numpy is calculating wrong

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy like this code

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1, 100000001).sum()
>>> a
987459712
```

I guess the result must be some like
5000000050000000

I noticed that until five numbers the result is ok.
Does someone knows what is happened?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in python 2.7 with numpy@1.11.2 or python3.5 and numpy@1.12.0. What are you using?

Comment: Also, changing the title of the question to something more precise would be a good idea...

Comment: Yes, if you do `a=np.arange(1,100000001).sum()` it gives `5000000050000000` as result

Answer (score 10):

Numpy is not doing a mistake here. This phenomenon is known as [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

```
x = np.arange(1,100000001)
print(x.sum())  # 987459712
print(x.dtype)  # dtype('int32')
```

The 32 bit integer type used in `arange` for the given input simply cannot hold 5000000050000000. At most it can take [2147483647](https://stackoverflow.com/a/94608/3005167).

If you explicitly use a larger integer or floating point data type you get the expected result.

```
a = np.arange(1, 100000001, dtype='int64').sum()
print(a)  # 5000000050000000

a = np.arange(1.0, 100000001.0).sum()
print(a)  # 5000000050000000.0
```

Comment: Sounds like a "mistake" to me, especially in Python where long integers are used as necessary. Sure `numpy` does its own arithmetic, but as a numeric package it should be better at dealing with computations, not worse.

Comment: @alexis I don't think this is a mistake because it is documented behavior. The docs say that by default `arange` infers the data type from the input. Since `100000001` is small enough it seems reasonable to use `int32`. Actually, since I work on 32bit Python and use integer arrays primarily for indexing I do appreciate that it uses a pointer-sized data type by default.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you are using Windows, where the data type of the result is a 32 bit integer (while for those using, say, Mac OS X or Linux, the data type is 64 bit).  Note that `5000000050000000 % (2**32) = 987459712`

Try using

```
a = np.arange(1, 100000001, dtype=np.int64).sum()
```

or

```
a = np.arange(1, 100000001).sum(dtype=np.int64)
```

---

P.S. Anyone not using Windows can reproduce the result as follows:

```
>>> np.arange(1, 100000001).sum(dtype=np.int32)
987459712
```