# X to the power of y where y is 10 or higher (I keep getting the same result)

Tags: c

Alright, soo the task at hand is to compute 10^10 where the first 10 is an integer called "base" and the second 10 is an unsigned integer called "exponent".

```
int base = 10; unsigned int exponent = 10; int i = 1; long long result = 1;
while(i<=exponent){
result = result*base;
i++;
}
printf("X^y = %ld\n\n", result);
```

Now I've tried this with a for loop, while loop, recursive functions etc. And my "result" value is still 1410065400 for some reason? It should be just a one with a bunch of zeros. If anyone got a simple solution to this problem I would be very happy to hear it. And if this has been posted before (didn't find anything on here about it tho) then I would gladly accept the link to that solution.

Comment: Save time, enable compiler warnings.  Compiler should have complained about incorrect printf specifier with `printf("X^y = %ld\n\n", result);`.  (Reconsider use of `"%ld"` with `long long`.)

Comment: OT and just to make sure: in C `^` is ***not*** the "power to"-operator.

Comment: I'm aware that the ^ is not the "power to" operator, that is just for the mathematical expression when printing out. And I am using compiler warnings (and currently have zero warnings when I compile).

Comment: You might like to read about *length modifiers*, You can use the `printf` documentation for this.

Comment: Or if you have an IDE, set a breakpoint at the printf and see what the internal value of result is.

Comment: @Pam: ... this is also possible without an IDE, using a stand alone debugger.

Comment: I use Codeblocks with the standard debugger that's included. But I found what I was looking for now, and like I mentioned in my comment below I will start reading up on length modifiers & printf documentation. Thank you for all your answers/inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As sad in comment, your format specifier is wrong in `printf` function. It should be like:

```
printf("X^y = %lli\n", result);
```

`lli` is the correct format specifier. Result:

```
X^y = 10000000000
```

Integer values in `C` programming language are `32 bits` and it can hold values that contains 10 digits but 10^10 is 11 digit so it overflows.

You can learn about more from this question:

[What is the maximum value for an int32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-an-int32)

Comment: Oh, I guess I missunderstood what you were saying, my apologies. Our teacher taught us in engineering class to print it with %d but I get the feeling I should really read up upon that printf documentation after all. This worked, thank you.

Comment: @ChrisE: The *conversion specifiers* `i` and `d` do the same, both can be used to printf an `int`. So `%lld`  would also do to printf a `long long int`.