# Not getting hh:mm:ss output for int32_t datatype but for uint64_t getting correct output

Tags: c++, qt

I want output in time format:

```
 inline int32_t toMsec(const QTime& time, const int32_t days = 0)
    {
        return (days * 24 * 3600 * 1000) + (time.hour() * 3600 * 1000) + (time.minute() * 60 * 1000) +
               (time.second() * 1000) + time.msec();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with the question in your title? What type are you talking about? The return type of the function? What does "not getting hh:mm:ss output" mean? You are asking it to return a single integer value, not formatted output.

Comment: What value is the function expected to return and for what input? Does the value you want it to return even fit in a `int32_t`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste. It also allows people to see how `QTime` is defined and whether you are using Qt.

Comment: Please specify exactly the intended output and actual output of your program. Phrases such as "I'm not getting the correct output.", or similar phrases, are not a sufficient description of the problem.

Comment: hh:mm:ss is time output which is formatted later as for uint64_t it is working correctly

Comment: when I right my code like these I am getting correct output inline uint64_t toMsec(const QTime& time, const uint64_t days = 0)
{
    return (days * 24 * 3600 * 1000) + (time.hour() * 3600 * 1000) + (time.minute() * 60 * 1000) +
           (time.second() * 1000) + time.msec();
}

Answer (score 3):

The maximum value that can be stored in an int32_t variable is around  2,147,483,647. ([Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-an-int32)). But in your case, if you want to calculate the number of mili-seconds in 100 days, the result will be:

```
100 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 = 8,640,000,000
```

that is higher than the maximum value that can be stored by `int32_t`. For `int64_t`, the maximum is pretty much higher, so you can keep the number of mili-seconds of 10 centuries on it:

```
10 * 100 * 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 = 31,536,000,000,000
```

Comment: changed the code this way but instead of updating hh:mm:ss it is giving mm:ss:ssss(day *24 * 3600 * 100000000) + (timeVar.toTime().hour() * 3600 * 1000000) + (timeVar.toTime().minute() * 60 * 10000) +
                                  (timeVar.toTime().second() * 100) + timeVar.toTime().msec()

Comment: @Neel Your code is simply returning an int32_t. Please update your code with the parts that generates the `hh::mm::ss` format. Lacking this part is the reason that you receive close votes for your Q.