# Sum of positive numbers is a negative number

Tags: c, sum

So this code is supposed to find the `minimum_sum` and `maximum_sum` (sum of [arr_elemnts-1] numbers) values of a sorted array of positive numbers (exemple `arr=[5,4,3,2,1]` gives `min_sum=1+2+3+4=10 max_sum=5+4+3+2=14`)

it works fine for most cases, but when I input the elements of the array as `140537896 243908675 670291834 923018467 520718469` instead of returning `min=1575456874 max=2357937445` it returns `min=1575456874 max=-1937029851` (I am a beginner, any idea what I did wrong ?)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sort(int n, long int arr[n])
{
    int aux;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
            {
                aux = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void sum(int n, long int arr[n])
{
    long int min_sum = 0;
    long int max_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        min_sum = min_sum + arr[i];
    }
    printf("min sum is : %ld \n", min_sum);
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        max_sum = max_sum + arr[i];
    }
    printf("max sum is : %ld",max_sum);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("----MIN MAX---- \n");
    do {
        printf("Enter n : ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n <= 0);
    long int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter arr[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%ld", &arr[i]);
    }
    sort(n, arr);
    sum(n, arr);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum value for an int32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94591/what-is-the-maximum-value-for-an-int32)

Comment: What is the output of `printf("%zu", sizeof(long));` on your system?

Comment: Unrelated - but as you have it, you don't need to sort. You just need to sum the entire array and find the smallest and largest items in the array as you scan over it. Then subtract those values from the original summation to get the "min sum" and "max sum".

Comment: If the items in the array are longs `long int arr[n]` then you should use a long and not an int when swapping them `int aux;`.

Comment: OP, this is a great learning experience for you as a C programmer, but it's pretty much a duplicate in this environment. Integer overflow is a thing and we all need to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, long ints are limited to 32 bits (maximum 2,147,483,647).

You could maybe try a long long int instead, which is 64 bits (maximum 9,223,372,036,854,775,807).

I'm not very familiar with c, but to expand on why the sum of big number would be negative, it is possible that when adding them together, some bits get ignored or replaced and become negative. You could try adding 1 to a 32 bit 2,147,483,647 to see what happens.

See [Integer overflow on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: `int` is only required to be 16 bits wide in C.

Comment: @adabsurdum good to know, thanks. Though, they did use a long int, so that would still be 32 bits right? Either way, their number is out of range.

Comment: The 16 bit width is the minimum required by C for `int`, but 32 bits is typical for desktop machines. `long int` must be at least 32 bits wide, and `long long int` must  be at least 64 bits wide. IIRC, Windows has 32 bit `long int`, while Linux has 64 bit `long int` on 64 bit machines, so you need to be careful there. But there are many other platforms with different implementation-specific widths.

Comment: _"to expand on why the sum of big number would be negative"_ -- signed integer overflow causes undefined behavior in C, but it is likely that the result was integer wrap around that lead to a negative result.

Comment: Let's not use Wikipedia as a source.

Comment: @nicomp Rather than only point out what not to use: "Let's not use Wikipedia as a source", advance your case with suggested better ideas of what to use.

Comment: @chux The obvious answer is any authoritative source at the bottom of the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 3):

> Sum of positive numbers is a negative number.

**Potential narrow sum**

The sum of OP's input may exceed the positive range of OP's `long`.
A case of signed integer overflow, undefined behavior, (UB).
Use a wider type to store the sum or detect potential overflow.

```
 140537896  (Not this small one)
 243908675  (Include the 4 greatest)
 670291834  (Include the 4 greatest)
 923018467  (Include the 4 greatest)
+520718469  (Include the 4 greatest)
----------
2357937445

2147483647 --> Max 32-bit signed integer
```

```
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
      if (arr[i] > LONG_MAX - min_sum) {
        printf("Type of min_sum is too narrow, use a wider type.\n");
        exit (-1);
      }
      min_sum = min_sum + arr[i];
    }
```

**Mixing types**

Code uses `int aux;` to store a `long`.  This is a problem when the `long` value does not fit in an `int`.  [@Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632802/sum-of-positive-numbers-is-a-negative-number/77632994#comment136863381_77632802)

Use the same type.

Answer (score 1):

The variable used to swap the entries in `sort` has type `int`. It should have type `long int` to avoid undefined behavior when then values in the array exceed the range of type `int`.

Here is a modified version of `sort`:

```
int sort(int n, long int arr[n]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j]) {
                long int aux = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that C23 has a new feature that can be used to avoid such silly mistakes: the `auto` keyword can now be used to let the compiler determine the type of the variable from that of the initializer, as is commonly used in C++.  With modern compilers configured to use the c23 standard `--std=c23`, you can write:

```
int sort(int n, long int arr[n]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j]) {
                auto aux = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that `sum` can be simplified to make fewer additions:

```
void sum(int n, const long int arr[n])
{
    long int min_sum = 0;
    long int max_sum = 0;

    if (n > 0) {
        long int middle_sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
            middle_sum = middle_sum + arr[i];
        }
        min_sum = arr[0] + middle_sum;
        max_sum = middle_sum + arr[n - 1];
    }
    printf("min sum is: %ld\n", min_sum);
    printf("max sum is: %ld\n", max_sum);
}
```

Finally, depending on the actual range of type `long int`, the sum of several large values may can an arithmetic overflow. Using a larger type is recommended, albeit not guaranteed to handle all cases:

```
void sum(int n, const long int arr[n])
{
    long long int min_sum = 0;
    long long int max_sum = 0;

    if (n > 0) {
        long long int middle_sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
            middle_sum = middle_sum + arr[i];
        }
        min_sum = arr[0] + middle_sum;
        max_sum = middle_sum + arr[n - 1];
    }
    printf("min sum is: %lld\n", min_sum);
    printf("max sum is: %lld\n", max_sum);
}
```